# MongoDB Spring Data Repository - Cache methods

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I need to have calls to MongoDB cached using spring @Cacheable annotation:

```
public interface SiteRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Site, String>{
    @Cacheable
    List<Site> findByStatus(Site.Status status);
}
```

Unfortunately, annotating any method in the interface with @Cacheable causes the following exception:

> Nov 22, 2014 7:11:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'example': Injection of autowired dependencies
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.example.repositories.mongodb.SiteRepository
>   com.example.siteRepo; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'siteRepository': Post-processing of
>   FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not
>   generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92]:
>   Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a
>   non-visible class; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1189)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4935)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5257)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.example.repositories.mongodb.SiteRepository
>   com.example.siteRepo; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'siteRepository': Post-processing of
>   FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not
>   generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92]:
>   Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a
>   non-visible class; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
>     ... 27 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'siteRepository': Post-processing of
>   FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not
>   generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92]:
>   Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a
>   non-visible class; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:115)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1465)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:917)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:860)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
>     ... 29 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not
>   generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92]:
>   Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a
>   non-visible class; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:218)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:477)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1656)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:112)
>     ... 36 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot
>   subclass final class class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
>     at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.create(Enhancer.java:285)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:206)
>     ... 43 more

I am looking for a way to cache calls to DB (which are quite expensive). Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotation-enable) on caches:

> Spring recommends that you only annotate **concrete classes** (and methods
>   of concrete classes) with the @Cache* annotation, **as opposed to
>   annotating interfaces**. You certainly can place the @Cache* annotation
>   on an interface (or an interface method), but this works only as you
>   would expect it to if you are using interface-based proxies. The fact
>   that Java annotations are not inherited from interfaces means that if
>   you are using class-based proxies ( proxy-target-class="true") or the
>   weaving-based aspect ( mode="aspectj"), then the caching settings are
>   not recognized by the proxying and weaving infrastructure, and the
>   object will not be wrapped in a caching proxy, which would be
>   decidedly bad.

Probably your cache configuration is colliding with the way that Spring creates implementations of your repository interfaces at runtime.

You could review your caching configuration to make it play nice with spring data (see [here](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/01/cacheable-overhead-in-spring.html) for different caching configuration options).

Or, you could do this:

```
public interface SiteRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Site, String>{
    List<Site> findByStatus(Site.Status status);
}

@Service
public class CachedSiteService {

    @Autowired
    private SiteRepository siteRepository;

    @Cacheable("sites")
    List<Site> findByStatus(Site.Status status) {
        return siteRepository.findByStatus(status);
    }

}
```

Comment: I ended up doing your second option via a service and caching it. I find it quite cumbersome as you need an extra service. I would expect the Spring people to enable @Cacheable on the repositories as well. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Does this also apply to Controller methods? If I add the @Cacheable to a method that returns a list of Objects, does the list get cached? How do I ensure the list s tied to an id?

Comment: Generally caching is frowned upon on Controller methods as by definition can have different Controllers seding same data ... but there is no technical reason why "@Cacheable" on a controller would not work  @AlexCon